# Spring AMQP with R2DBC

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, r2dbc

I'm using Spring R2DBC and Spring AMQP (RabbitMQ).
I'm trying to call some Mono @Transactionnal methods that modify the database when receiving a message from RabbitMQ but it seems that I'm not in context know the R2DBC connection :

```
2023-05-05 11:06:56.509 ERROR 72872 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] reactor.core.publisher.Operators:error l.324 : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConnectionHolder available
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConnectionHolder available
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.R2dbcTransactionManager$ConnectionFactoryTransactionObject.getConnectionHolder(R2dbcTransactionManager.java:554) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
```

My code is the following :

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = MessagesListenerConfiguration.USER_DELETED_QUEUE_NAME)
    public void onUserDeleted(final Integer userId) {
        Mono.when(
                        vendorService.onUserDeleted(userId),
                        customerService.onUserDeleted(userId)
                )
                .subscribe();
```

How to switch from the rabbitmq listener context to the r2dbc context as it is done when receiving request API on a WebFlux Controller ?